# How to retrieve the current page name AND any variables

Tags: php, get

I'm using `basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])` but this only gives me the page name e.g.

http://www.mysite.com/helloworld.php?name=Dan

I can only get **"helloworld.php"**.

I need **"helloworld.php?name=Dan"**

Comment: `var_dump($_SERVER)` to see what information `$_SERVER` holds

Comment: `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`  `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`, and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and [many more](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

In your case, you can get it like:

```
$whatiwant = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

or

```
$whatiwant = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all the query strings from the URL. You can use this:

```
echo basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$full_link = "http://" . $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] . $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try with:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

it will returns you:

```
/helloworld.php?name=Dan
```

But if you do:

```
trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/')
```

you will get:

```
helloworld.php?name=Dan
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the variable query string if available:

```
echo isset($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]) ? $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] : "";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI];
```

You can read more about $_SERVER [here.](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will returned **helloworld.php?name=Dan**.

You can try `print_r($_SERVER)` for getting more from **SERVER** variable.